# Unable to locate button element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can see the enabled button while running. I can select that button using Selenium IDE and the xpath. But when it comes to running using WebDriver it is not able to find the element.

Comment: Please add your web driver code and  html code with question.

Comment: It might be a wait issue since page might be taking long to load or that element might be under a frame or iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the localhost? because sometimes if it takes some extra seconds for the Web Browser to load (for example Firefox), then when Selenium tries to do the action it doesn't find the elements obviously resulting your error.

Use the [pause](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#pause) command, for example 5 seconds, so that the Selenium waits 5 seconds before the action is executed, giving time for the website to load.

Try the coding somewhere on this level

```
driver.manage().timeOuts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```